# How can I add my movie rank to google

Tags: google

Google has added two of my rivals to the search result, I'm jealous 
How did they do that?

[image]

Comment: You need to look at using [structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) in your website which talks about the movie

Comment: Google uses data from trusted sources such as Wikipedia, Google Reviews, and IMDB. Once I had a similar curiosity and I searched around to find where the metrics came from. I found my answer. While I have no idea where these specific metrics are coming from, we simply do not enough actionable information in your question to know, you perhaps can do a search and see what you get. Cheers!!